# XP Hard Shutdown Brings back same screen that was hanging

Tags: shutdown

The computer hangs on my mom's e-mail splash screen (The Bat). When I do a hard shutdown, the Lenovo splash screen comes on and then the same desktop and splash screen. It is hanging and I can see the computer working on the tower. Nothing else will work for me to bring up the task mgr. It's been like this for over an hour. What can she do?

Comment: How are you doing the hard shutdown?  Either it isn't really a hard shutdown, or it is resuming from hibernate instead of booting.  What version of Windows is it?

Comment: It's my 95 year old Mom (poor thing). She's holding the on/off button in until the computer shuts off. It's WinXP.

Comment: Everything I've told her to try to bring up task mgr. doesn't work. Right clicking on start doesn't work. Something is hanging. Can she use any of the F keys to go into safe mode when it's coming back on?

Comment: Have you seen this for yourself?  Is it that it is booting to the same screen, or it is booting normally, The Bat loads automatically, and then hangs?